# Loop in Except Script Variable Getting Value from Text File

Tags: expect

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
 
# Set variables
 set hostname [lindex $argv 0]
 set username [lindex $argv 3]
 set password [lindex $argv 1]
 set devname  [lindex $argv 4]
 set enablepassword [lindex $argv 2]
 set conft 0
# Log results
 log_file -a ~/scripts/ExpectScripts/9120CiscoAPs/results.log
 
# Announce which device we are working on and at what time
 send_user "\n"
 send_user ">>>>>  Working on $hostname $devname @ [exec date] <<<<<\n"
 send_user "\n"
 
# Don't check keys
 set timeout 30
 spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=30 $username\@$hostname
 expect "User:"
 send "$username\n"
 expect "Password:"
 send "$password\n"
 expect "*>"
 set f [open "aprebootlist2.txt"]
 set aps [split [read $f] "\n"]
 close $f
 foreach ap $aps {
 send "config ap reset $ap\n"
   expect {
          "*n)" {send "y\n"}
          "*invalid." {send "\r"}
          }
  expect eof
  close
 }
  send "\r"
  expect "*>"
  send "logout\n"
 expect "*(y/N)"
 send "n\r"
 exit
```

This should log into a cisco wireless controller and basically run the command "ap config reset apvariable" a bunch of times. I tried to create a loop getting the variable for ap name from a text file.  The script logs into the controller, reads the first name in the file, than fails with the below error.  What am I doing wrong?
Error is:

```
Cisco Controller) >send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "config ap reset $ap\n""
    ("foreach" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"foreach ap $aps {
 send "config ap reset $ap\n"
   expect {
          "*n)" {send "y\n"}
          "*invalid." {send "\r"}
          }
  expect eof
  ..."
    (file "./rebootapcommands2.exp" line 29)
```

Comment: Why do you close the spawned connection inside the loop? That's why it's not open.

Comment: So I need to put the close statement after the last } ?